# How to do a name similarity using clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, similarity

I have a very big -super big- database of names.
The task is to find all the similar names (of the same person per se) despite some diffrences like :

1. first name, second name inversed **-->** John Doe & Doe John
2. two names or more (same ones) with light changes, maybe some
   letters misplaced or something else **-->** Jonh Doe & John Deo
3. two names with some letters added **-->** Johhn Doe & Johnn Doee &
   John Doe
4. names where another middle name inserted **-->** John Blair Campbell Doe & John Blair Doe

And so on..

I tried using the classical methods like ***soundex*** and ***leveshtein*** but the results were not very good, had results like : Amine depi and Amina dope are in the same group while they're diffrent
and It would take very long to perform the task on just a fraction on the data, as for my database, it would directly crash after a long time

I also thought of using another approach like ***cosine*** which uses numerical values and I though of finding a way of representing the names in a numerical way, or convert them (something like word2vec), I actually though of using directly word2vec with the whole database of namems as the text, but as expected it didn't work. Tried to codify the names in a low level way, like code ASCII for exemple, but the results weren't good neither.

**So I thought of Clustering**.
So I tried using *DBSCAN*. I found a way to use DBSCAN clustering with a custom distance metric and used leveshtein distance. (If you ask me why DBSCAN? It is because I don't know the numbers of similar groups of names which are in the database in the beginning)

I did have some results, but very poor performance overall. It would either give the same exact ones, John Doe and John Doe int he same cluster, or nothing at all, and would even skip some exact ones.

Do you have a suggestion for performing this task ? preferbly using clsutering or another smart way since the database is very big (more than 500 000 line and up to millions ) so I cannot iterate alot.

I am open to suggestions or propositions !

Especially if you worked on something like this previously or similar to this, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try AgglomerativeClustering.

Sample code:

```
clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(
    n_clusters=None,
    distance_threshold=0.3  # smaller threshold meaning more strict similarities, and more clusters
).fit(your_vectorized_name_list)

print(f'total clusters: {clustering.n_clusters_}')
```